# How to append an html element when using flatpickr

Tags: flatpickr

I'm having the weirdest problem and I'm stumped.

I'm using flatpickr as a date picker on my site, and this tool works really well, however I'm thinking I would like to add an additional image on the popup dialog.  I'm thinking 'I can do this!' and so off I go.

I found the onOpen() hook and knew it was the perfect function for what I needed to do.  Then I wrote some jQuery to reference the correct area on the dialog and then .append(htmlString)

My code for generating the popup and my configuration options are:

```
    $dateRangeInputs.flatpickr({
    altInput: true,
    mode: 'range',
    onOpen: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
        instance.prevMonthNav.append("<img src='/ui/images/icons/arrow-left.svg'>");
    }
});
```

The problem is the 'htmlString' is treated entirely as text, ignoring the html instructions, so I get the following HTML turning up in the dialog.

```
<svg version="1.1" ...> ... </svg>
&lt;img src='/ui/images/icons/arrow-left.svg'&gt;</span>
```

I've included a picture also, for those of you who prefer visual explanations.
[image: screen shot of the inserted htmlString]

I have checked and rechecked the jQuery append() command, it should be processing the htmlString argument correctly.  My only thought is that there is something in the flatpickr library that is only allowing text to be included.  I think my best help will come from others who are using flatpickr.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out!
I needed to wrap the instance property as a jQuery selector, like this:

```
onOpen: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    $(instance.prevMonthNav).append("<img src='/ui/images/icons/arrow-left.svg'>");
}
```